processDebugManifest FAILED
Getting this error suddenly with running android build

{
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/art": "^1.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.3.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "^3.0.3",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/picker": "^1.8.0",
    "@react-native-community/progress-bar-android": "^1.0.5",
    "@react-native-community/progress-view": "1.4.1",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "^0.2.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^15.1.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^15.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^15.7.0",
    "@react-native-voice/voice": "^3.2.4",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-plugin-idx": "^2.4.0",
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "idx": "^2.5.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "mobx": "^5.15.5",
    "mobx-react": "^6.2.5",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-icons": "^3.10.0",
    "react-native": "0.63.3",
    "react-native-barcode-builder": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-barcode-mask": "^1.2.4",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.36.0",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-config": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.3.2",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-global-props": "^1.1.5",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^4.5.1",
    "react-native-otp-verify": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-pdf": "^6.3.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-razorpay": "^2.2.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.10.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.11.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-walkthrough-tooltip": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-webengage": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.26.1",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "s": "^1.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1"
  },
}

Require community help to solve.
